# Mvc.WebViewPage<T>.Model.get returned null and Id in Create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting this error while trying to create object while using DropDown and ListBox lists

> System.NullReferenceException System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

Model

```
public class Game
    { 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publishers { get; set; }
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public string ImageLink { get; set; }

    public Game()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    public int Id { get;  set; }
    public string Title { get;  set; }
    public object Category { get;  set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get;  set; }
    public string ImageLink { get;  set; }

    public GameViewModel(int id, string title, List<Category> category, Publisher publisher, string imageLink)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Category = category;
        this.Publisher = publisher;
        this.ImageLink = imageLink;
    }
```

Create View Model

```
 public class CreateGameViewModel{

    public Game Game { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Publishers { get; private set; }
    public int[] SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public CreateGameViewModel()
    {
    this.Game = new Game();
    }

    public CreateGameViewModel(List<Models.Category> categories, List<Models.Publisher> publishers)
    {
        Categories = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

        Publishers = publishers.Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Text = p.Name, Value = p.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    }
}
```

My controller

```
 GET
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var publishers = _db.Publishers.ToList();
        var categories = _db.Categories.ToList();
        var gameVM = new CreateGameViewModel(categories: categories, publishers: publishers);
        return View(gameVM);
    }
 POST 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateGameViewModel game)
    {
        try
        {
            var categories = _db.Categories.Where(c => game.SelectedCategory.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
            game.Game.Categories = categories;
            _db.Games.Add(game.Game);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My view(where error shows up)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Game.PublisherID, Model.Publishers)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)
```

I'm also having editor for id and PublisherID in this create view which surely isn't right, but I'm not sure where to pinpoint that issue, while the other one exist.

Could someone take a look at this code?

Answer (score 0):

So i think your problem is `Game` is not defined, so when you try and do `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Game.PublisherID, Model.Publishers)` it's game being null that gives your error

Your code:

```
public class CreateGameViewModel
{
    public Game Game { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Publishers { get; private set; }
    public int[] SelectedCategory { get; set; }

    public CreateGameViewModel()
    {
       this.Game = new Game();
    }

    public CreateGameViewModel(List<Models.Category> categories, 
                               List<Models.Publisher> publishers)
    {
        Categories = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, 
     Value = c.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

        Publishers = publishers.Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Text = p.Name, 
     Value = p.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Fix:

```
public class CreateGameViewModel
{
    public Game Game { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Publishers { get; private set; }
    public int[] SelectedCategory { get; set; }

    public CreateGameViewModel()
    {
       this.Game = new Game();
    }

    public CreateGameViewModel(List<Models.Category> categories, 
                               List<Models.Publisher> publishers)
          :this()
    {
        Categories = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, 
     Value = c.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

        Publishers = publishers.Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Text = p.Name, 
     Value = p.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The minor difference being the **:this()** at the second constructor, this should call the first constructor initialising `Game` which should stop the error from happening

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately problem persists, tho there was slight change in that id and publisherId in my broken view started to show 0 (http://oi64.tinypic.com/2luwitj.jpg). I'm suspecting that the model of game itself might be the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I believe you need to set it to the current models value otherwise it defaults to a value like 0

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, the view in pic doesnt work correctly, It shouldn't have id or publisherId as settable. I did fixed the database just now, since it didn't have connections it needed(http://oi65.tinypic.com/2rny2z8.jpg), but the "id" box in CreateView still persists, and so does the error.

Comment: So if you have a list of three items with id's 1,2,3 you need to set your selected id to the default value. It may be worth searching around as I'm sure you could quite easily find the answer you need :). If not you can always open a new question for this new issue